# Badge Request, Incremental badges for some of the 'Only Awarded Once' badges

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

It would be very interesting to be able to earn a few badges more than once.
I would like to see a system for these badges where you can earn them as many times as you want, but each time it gets harder and harder.

For example:

> Commentator : Leave 10 comments on posts.
>   Commentator x2: Leave 100 comments on posts.
>   Commentator x3: Leave 1000 comments on posts.
>
> Strunk and White : Edit 100 posts.
>   Strunk and White x2: Edit 1000 posts.
>   ...

This could be implemented for many of the badges.

Comment: Autobiographerx2: Completed all user profile fields 10 times

Comment: Hmmm...I didn't think of that one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds pretty much like a amalgamation of several different requests. In some cases I am in favor of having certain badges have tiers for bronze/silver/gold with the difficulty growing of course (we already have this with a whole slew of other badges).

Comment: Well, in this case a bronze badge would stay bronze.  The prestige would be seeing an x5 next to my Commentator badge.

Comment: (100,000 Comments!)

Comment: Is there prestige in a 100,000 comments badge? Or is it just the implicit admission of addiction?

Comment: Actually, if you leave that many comments, you're almost sure to get the pundit badge.

Comment: You are likely to be an addict too...